# Giving error on facebook login (omniauth-facebook)

Tags: omniauth-facebook

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Can't Load URL",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191,
      "fbtrace_id": "DimFAkcyc2F"
   }
}
```

Comment: could you please add the relevant code generating this error and also format the error message to make it a little easier to read please